# Running server and react app from one place

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, deployment

I'm trying to set up a server and react app to both serve from one place, and host from one domain. This gives me the advantage of one repo and being able to use server side cookies instead of auth tokens.

See also this link: https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3

I also prefer to use typescript.

I really think this would be a good approach, but it is hard to find resources. All courses, free or paid, are working with separate React / Angular frontends, which then need to fetch data from a backend on a separate domain.

**Does anyone know a good resource how to combine a react frontend and an express backend and host it from one place?** Or are there good reasons not to do that, which I just don't see at the moment?

Comment: Not that this is really the kind of question SO is for, but just to respond: your question doesn't really make sense. You can't run two concurrent servers from the same domain. I think what you should be doing is combining them. You could have a server that not only does all the backend stuff (like provide endpoints for fetching data and so on), but it also serves all the front end's files.

Comment: The reason they're usually separate in courses/tutorials is because it's a good idea to think of them as separate entities. The front end is the UI that is displayed on the client's machine, and the back end is the server that does all the back end functionality like authenticating users or providing endpoints for fetching data. In general the 2 aren't (and shouldn't be) tightly coupled. Your front end should work with ANY server that has the same endpoints and responses it's expecting, and vice versa

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444. I dont mean to run 2 servers - the express server will just run the static (built) html and js files. Much in the same way as developing an app with pug, for example.

Comment: I'm not too sure what pug is, but I mean to answer your question then yes it's a perfectly fine approach to combine a frontend and backend into a single entity that's hosted from one domain. If you have *specific* questions then you can ask those, but in general - yes, it's fine for a server to both host the frontend's files *and* provide the API for said frontend.

Comment: Sure, updated the question to be more specific towards typeorm & react

Comment: [Crisp React](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) I'm the author.

Comment: @winwiz Thanks so much, definitely gonna have a look at it.